# json-rpc and p2p port protocol type

Tags: json-rpc, port, p2p

What type of port protocol do json-rpc and p2p use? does it use TCP or UDP?

If possible, can you config or reprogram the open-source and compile the source to use TCP only if it also uses UDP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What type of port protocol do json-rpc and p2p use? does it use TCP or UDP?

Both use TCP.

> If possible, can you config or reprogram the open-source and compile the source to use TCP only if it also uses UDP?

Certainly. It's open source, you can change whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks so before making possible changes, does it require UDP by default or only allowing TCP will work?

Since im trying to run in a network where some TCP port are unblocked and UDP are completely blocked

Comment: They use TCP already ... UDP is not used.

Comment: oh ok thanks then no code modification needed